# Redisson RLocalCachedMap doesnt sync

Tags: java, caching, redis, redisson

I use redisson RLocalCachedMap with **syncStrategy(LocalCachedMapOptions.SyncStrategy.UPDATE)** in my application.
I have 3 instances of application running in 3 container's. I was expecting the RLocalCachedMap count to match in all container but the count is different after few hours (all instance had correct count as cache was preloaded at start-up), any reason for this behaviour ?

127.0.0.1:6379> HLEN tags_rlocal
(integer) 32319

Container1 count - 32319,
Container2 count - 19313,
Container3 count - 19412

I do not see any redis related exceptions in the logs, any ideas

Comment: Seems all containers has different names. Can you share the code?